# How would you say "extremes of the word" with an adjective of qualification?

Tags: meaning, word-request

How would you say *extremes of the word* or *edges of the word* or *characters at the end and at the beginning of the word* (I don't know which one is correct, if any) using adjectives of qualification?

By extremes or edges of the word I mean, supposing the word is *hello*, the extremes would be **h** and **o**,  but if I have another expression *%123awe&*, the extremes would be **%** and **&**.

It would be nice if we could refer to those letters as *extreme letters* or *extreme digits* or *edged digits*.  Is one of this correct? Which alternatives do I have?

Comment: 'First' and 'last letters' are the usual designations.

Comment: I would just use *first/last* letter(s) or *beginning/ending* letter(s). Have never heard "extreme" used this way though.

Comment: Or "first and last character", especially if you are a programmer and are refering to a string.

Comment: This is an old question, but since no one has yet said as much, do note that "digits" refers _specifically_ to numerals, in English.

Answer (score 2):

In programming, specifically regular expressions, those are referred to as *word boundaries*, but that's not understood in general English.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a good word for this that everyone would recognize. If you want to use a shorter phrase, you should define it first:

> First, we need to look at the first and last characters in the word. Let's call these "edge characters" for short.

Depending on what you're talking about, "bounding characters" could also be a good choice.